# Objectify - create cost-effective entities. best practise for entity design

Tags: java, google-app-engine, entity, objectify

is there a tutorial for a cost-effective entity design?

If I make a small sample and say I want to store **users** and **groups**. These groups have a **List of users**. If any user wants to join this group I have to check is this group existing and the user isn't part of the group.

***My question is not how to do this. The question is for a good entity-design or a good objectify-using.***

Here is some shortened sample code how I would do this:

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Cache
@Embed
public class User {
    @Id Long id;
    @Index String name;
    String passwordHash;
}
```

**Group.java**

```
@Entity
@Cache
public class Group {
    @Id Long id;
    @Index Long groupAdministratorUserId;
    @Index String name;
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
    @Index Boolean isPublic;
}
```

using

```
if (!app.authenticate(getRequest(), getResponse())) 
{
    // Not authenticated
    setStatus(Status.CLIENT_ERROR_UNAUTHORIZED);
}
else
{
    Group newGroup = ofy().load().type(Group.class).id(Long.parseLong(id)).now(); // is it correct that the embedded data is already loaded?
    // following check and insert is only for illustration!
    newGroup.getUsers().contains(connectedUser);
    newGroup.getUsers().add(connectedUser);
    ofy().save().entity(newGroup).now();
}
```

**My "overhead" (authentication)**

```
public class MyVerifier extends LocalVerifier {
    private User fetched;

    public User getFetched() {
        return fetched;
    }

    @Override
    public char[] getLocalSecret(String identifier) {
        // this is behind search... and another list()
        // User fetched = ofy().load().type(User.class).filter("name", userName).first().now();
        fetched = User.searchByExactName(identifier);
        if (fetched != null)
        {
            return fetched.getPasswordHash().toCharArray();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

P.S. I know the page from google: https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/BestPractices

But that is not what I'm searching for

Answer (score 0):

I would store the list of groups IDs the `User` entity. No need to use `@Embed`. What the best solution is really depends on what the most common operations will be in your application. Based on what you said I would recommend the following:

```
@Entity
@Cache
public class User {
    @Id long id;
    String name;
    String passwordHash;
    List<Long> groups;
    // constructor left out for brevity.
}

@Entity
@Cache
public class Group {
    @Id long id;
    long adminId;
    String name;
    boolean isPublic;
    // constructor left out for brevity.
}

User user1 = new User(userName1, passwordHash1);
User user2 = new User(userName2, passwordHash2);

Key<User> user1Key = ofy().save().entity(user1).now(); // Create two users.
Key<User> user2Key = ofy().save().entity(user2).now(); // The don't have any groups yet.

long adminId = user1Key.getId();
Group group = new Group(name, adminId, isPublic)
Key<Group> groupKey = ofy().save().entity(group).now(); // Create a group

user2.addToGroup(groupKey.getId()); // This adds the group ID to the User.groups list.
ofy().save().entity(user2).now(); // Add user2 to group.
```

To save costs (specifically on small datastore operations during updates) make sure to create as few indexes as possible. Start with few `@Index`es and add them as necessary.

Comment: Is this really an improvement? I changed my code to a version with storing only ids but didn't noticed a change. The number of datastore calls is the same.

Comment: What you want to look at is the number of [datastore reads, writes, and small datastore operations](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing) shown in the GAE Admin Console. The number of datastore calls is not necessary the same as the number of reads/writes/small operations you are charged for. [Appstats](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appstats) reports the number of read/write/small operations that you are billed for.

Comment: yes I know. With my "overhead" by identifying the user and so on I have 12 RPCs with both variants 4 memcache.Get & Set an 2 datastore.Get & RunQuery. Without saving the new id

Comment: the bill is for both the same: _cost=380, billed_ops=[DATASTORE_READ:5, DATASTORE_SMALL:3]_

Comment: What is responsible for datastore.RunQuery? From your sample code it looks like you are getting everything by ID. Can you post the code you use in order to generate the AppStats & billing data?

Comment: how I said there is an authentication. I edited the main question

Comment: Without one list() operation I get the following: `11 RPCs, cost=220, billed_ops=[DATASTORE_READ:3, DATASTORE_SMALL:1]`. But that is micro-optimizing and I'm searching for a good entity-design. Like you said to store the Longs (userid) and so on.

Comment: Can you share the code so that I can test it with appstats myself? If you like the answer feel free to accept it :)

Comment: as I said, this change is currently no improvement to my working code. Furthermore by storing the id I have to read out other data by another function. I think objectify is clever enough to do this "mapping" effective. P.S. I nearly provided the most of the code you need. the residue is REST and so on